# Cookie update fine other browser except google chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, setcookie

Cookies are update fine in all browsers but in google chrome, it fails to update the cookies.

Bellow is my code:

```
public static string CustomerName
{
    get { return CookieStore.GetCookie("customername"); }
    set { CookieStore.SetCookie("customername", value.ToString(), TimeSpan.FromHours(24), true); }
}

public static void SetCookie(string key, string value, TimeSpan expires, bool http = false)
{
    HttpCookie encodedCookie = new HttpCookie(key, value);
   // encodedCookie.HttpOnly = http;

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key] != null)
    {
        var cookieOld = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];
        cookieOld.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(expires);
        cookieOld.Value = encodedCookie.Value;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieOld);
    }
    else
    {
        encodedCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(expires);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(encodedCookie);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem found in **SetCookie** function. you need to replace the following line of code

```
var cookieOld = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];
```

with the following line while updating your cookie.

```
var cookieOld = new HttpCookie(key);
```

Bellow is the complete **SetCookie** function.

```
 public static void SetCookie(string key, string value, TimeSpan expires, bool http = false)
        {
        
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key] != null)
            {
                
                var cookieOld = new HttpCookie(key);
                cookieOld.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(expires);
                cookieOld.Value = value;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieOld);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpCookie encodedCookie = new HttpCookie(key, value);
                encodedCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(expires);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(encodedCookie);
            }
        }
```